# Why does Arrays.asList(listOfPoints).contains(point) work?

Tags: java, list, compare

I came across the following code in an example and do not understand why it works.

First an array of points are defined with random values:

```
Point[] randPoints = new Point[5];
        
        for (int i=0; i<randPoints.length; i++)
            randPoints[i] = new Point( (int)(Math.random() * 40), 
                                       (int) (Math.random()* 10) );
```

Then there is a loop checking if these points have the current x,y position:

```
for ( int y = 0; y < 10; y++ )
        {
          for ( int x = 0; x < 40; x++ )
          {
            if ( Arrays.asList( randPoints ).contains( new Point(x,y) ) )
              System.out.print( "P" );
            else
              System.out.print( "." );
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
```

What does Arrays.asList(randPoints) return for the comparison done in contains()?  And why is it possible to do this comparison?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Hint: all the standard java library classes have excellent javadoc. Read that first. Seriously, why do think other people should write down for you again what is already nicely explained?!

Comment: That javadoc would told you that asList returns a List object. And the javadoc of the List interface would have told you how that contains method is supposed to work. Seriously again, that is the nature of learning programming: to dig into stuff to find out yourself. Asking others is a valid approach, but make it your last option, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

All that is happening here is that the array is being wrapped in a `List` container, and `contains` (which is a List method) is being invoked.  To see what contains does, just read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).

**Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).**

You can easily do this without wrapping the array.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answer. I now understand how this is done. What I did not get was that the Arrays.asList(randPoints) returns a list of "Point". And that each "Point" is simply defined by the (x,y) combination. After understanding this it is easy to see why a comparison can be made in ...contains(new Point(x,y)) part.